# Conversion to base64 with php

Tags: php

I'm converting an image upload to base64, but I'm also trying to not have to store the image on my server unfortunately this code stores the file on my server is there a way to have it delete the file after it it encoded to base64?

Here is my code..

```
    if(isset($_FILES['t1']['name'])){
    $file = rand(0, 10000000).$_FILES['t1']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['t1']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
        if($fp = fopen($file,"rb", 0))
        {
           $picture = fread($fp,filesize($file));
           fclose($fp);
           // base64 encode the binary data, then break it
           // into chunks according to RFC 2045 semantics
           $base64 = base64_encode($picture);
           $tag1 = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$base64.'" alt="" />';
           $css = 'url(data:image/png;base64,'.str_replace("\n", "", $base64).'); ';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: easiest way for you: change 3rd line `if ($file = $_FILES['t1']['tmp_name'])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

so

```
....
$css = 'url(data:image/png;base64,'.str_replace("\n", "", $base64).'); ';
unlink($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_FILES['t1']['name'])){
    $file = rand(0, 10000000).$_FILES['t1']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['t1']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
           $fileCon = file_get_contents($file) ;
           // base64 encode the binary data, then break it
           // into chunks according to RFC 2045 semantics
           $base64 = base64_encode($fileCon);
           $tag1 = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$base64.'" alt="" />';
           $css = 'url(data:image/png;base64,'.str_replace("\n", "", $base64).'); ';
           unlink($file);
    }
```

if you not moving file from temp file will remove auto or if moving it you can unlink

good luck

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_FILES['t1']['tmp_name'] like a normal file.

So you should be able to do this:

```
if(isset($_FILES['t1']['name'])){
    $file = $_FILES['t1']['tmp_name'];
    if($fp = fopen($file,"rb", 0))
    {
        $picture = fread($fp,filesize($file));
        fclose($fp);
        // base64 encode the binary data, then break it
        // into chunks according to RFC 2045 semantics
        $base64 = base64_encode($picture);
        $tag1 = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$base64.'" alt="" />';
        $css = 'url(data:image/png;base64,'.str_replace("\n", "", $base64).'); ';
    }
}
```

If that's no good, you can use @cryptic's solution and just unlink() the file.

Comment: This might not work with open_basedir and/or safe_mode. You need move_uploaded_file() first.

Comment: Ah, that's quite possible. However, if those settings would allow it, I feel like it's a clean solution. If not, yeah, you need to move it and unlink() it afterwards.